# How to design a database entity relational diagram for a pet shop?

Tags: database, vb.net, erd

What should be my order product foreign key if I have 3 different product table which is care, groom, product tables. What should be the pk and foreign key?

Here's my database look like, it has no relations at all:

[image: here's my database look like, it has no relational at all please i need some help]

Comment: Looks like a very nice homework :-)

Comment: You shouldn't have three different tables for a start.  You should have one `Product` table and then a `ProductType` table that has three records. The `Product` table then has a foreign key to the `ProductType` table.

Comment: You will need to explain you products in plain English to start with. Are `care` and `groom` child tables of `product`?

Comment: "3 different product table"...that's your first mistake. If you have a single conceptual "thing" like a product, represent it with a single table. If there are different types of product, give them a ProductType field. Then have another table listing all the possible product types and have a foreign key between them. That, in a nutshell, is the basic principle of E-R design which you need to get into your head.

Comment: We can't tell you exactly what to do in this situation since "pet shop" is not a single homogeneous being with a single design, we don't know the specific requirements of the specific business and what things it needs to represent and store data about, nor how they relate to each other. But if you get the hang of identifying your business entities and abstracting them out to a sufficiently high level, then suddenly it becomes much easier to do design the database.